# Learning Java - Don't understand decrement in this example

Tags: java

```
public class Power {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int e;
    int result;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        result = 1;
        e = i;

        while(e > 0) {
            result *=2;
```

// what is e-- for in this example? if e=i after each iteration of i<10 then I don't get why e is decremented. Thanks in advance!

```
            e--;
        }

        System.out.println("2 to the " +i + " power is " + result);
    }


}
```

}

Comment: I strongly recommend learning to use a debugger, as soon as possible.  It will show you very clearly what is happening to each variable as your program runs.

Answer (score 3):

Decrementimg `e` is nessessary to avoid an infinite loop. But read on to see how the entire method can be done as this expression:

```
1 << i;
```

Unless `e` is decremented, the while condition

```
while(e > 0)
```

If true initially will remain true.

However, this equivalent code would be preferable:

```
for (int e = i; e > 0; e--) {
    result *= 2;
}
```

Because it is clearer what is going on.

Less clear perhaps, but far more elegant would be this:

```
result << e;
```

Since multiplying by two is the same as left bit shift 1.

---

In fact the whole loop may be replaced by just one line:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    System.out.println("2 to the " +i + " power is " + (1 << i));
```

no need for the variables `result` or `e`.

Answer (score 2):

The e is basically used as a counter for the amount of times the power should be done. Since it is a power, 2 has to be multiplied by i that many times, so e acts as the "counter", so 2 is multiplied by itself the corresponding amount of times.

Each time `e--` occurs, 2 is multiplied by itself, so when e is equal to i and e is decremented, 2 is continuously multiplied by itself until it reaches the specified amount: i.

Comment: So let's break it down. For each iteration of the loop, you are finding 2^ith power, correct? So in each iteration, you have to multiply 2 by itself "i" times. Therefore, you set `e=i`. Then, you keep decrementing "e" until "e" is equal to 0, and for each one of these operations, you multiply 2 by itself. Therefore, by the end, you have multiplied 2 by itself "i" times. I understand it may be hard to conceptualize, but try reading what I wrote very slowly and making sense of each part. Let me know if you want further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This is my program, which is an accepted way when calculating exponents.

```
 you can use Math.pow(x, y)..which is x^y..(^ is not xor here) 



 import acm.program.*;


    public class Exponents extends ConsoleProgram {

      public void run(){
          for (int n = 0; n <= 10; n++) {

                println("2 to the power of " + n + " = " + Math.pow(2,n)); 

         } 

      }
    private int raiseIntPower (int n){
       int total = 0;
       for( int n = 0; n <= 10; n++){
         total = Math.pow(2, n);

      } 

    return total; 
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The e is deincremented so that program can keep setting a new value for integer result. It's being used a counter in the loop.